# SQL overwrite column value in stored procedure during insert

Tags: sql-server, string, stored-procedures, str-replace

I'd like to default a column value despite what value passed on from front end. I use a stored procedure to manage the insert and update.

I have tried to use replace but it fails.

```
alter procedure project
(
    @PROJECTNAME NVARCHAR(150),
    @ProjectSid INT,
)    
INSERT into sa.project (Projectname, sid)
values (
    @PROJECTNAME = Replace(@PROJECTNAME,@PROJECTNAME,'Default'),
    @ProjectSid = Replace(@ProjectSid,@ProjectSid,100)
)
```

I get this error when tried to executed

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

What I am doing wrong? I'm executing above in SQL server. I don't want to change the schema to have default value as this scenario is specific to one module.

Comment: Make it simple, just `INSERT into sa.project (Projectname, sid) values ('Default',100)`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I only want to change the value if it comes from users. If the users didn't key in value, I'd like to leave it blank.

Comment: Please show examples of the different use cases, and the outcome you want.

Comment: Thanks Dale. I created a mode flag to distinguish the requests come from different modules then I assigned the default values to the module which I wanted to change. that worked. Thanks for looking into the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by created a mode flag to distinguish the requests come from different modules then I assigned the default values to the module which I wanted to change.